# How do I mount a specific folder within my external harddrive in fstab?

Tags: linux, filesystems, raspberry-pi, mount

The reason I want to do this is because I know ntfs format does not support chmod and I need specific directories with specific permission. How would I do this?

fstab only allows me to specify drives, for example /dev/sda1

I cannot do /dev/sda1/someDirectory

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Minor correction - `mount` (and thus `fstab`) allows you to specify _block devices_, which are usually _partitions_ and rarely _drives_.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, if you just have a couple of directories usable by certain users and hidden to others is to mount the device somewhere only root can reach (i.e. the mount point should be in a directory owned by root and with search permissions only for owner).  Then bind-mount the important subdirectories to mount points with appropriate access for your target users.

Comment: So you are saying mount the drive first, then mount the folders in the drive that I want special permissions to?